# Should we have a homework policy?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community, close-reasons

**Background**

There has been some ongoing discussion regarding whether it makes sense to have a "no-effort homework" close reason.

A recent question asks whether we should [add a close reason for zero effort homework](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/add-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-homework), but the most upvoted answer there (with only 4 votes) is largely a survey of other sites policies.

**The Decision**

Should we adopt a homework policy, and add a no effort homework close reason for it?

---

My idea here is that we'll have two answers, one for the close-reason and one against. Let's see if we can get consensus! We'll wait for at least 10+ upvotes before pulling the trigger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, we should adopt a homework policy and introduce a new "no-effort homework" reason to close a question.

Comment: This has been done! The new reason reads like "This question is missing context or other details..."

Comment: But then we should also write up the policy and link to it from that close reason.

Comment: That sounds right @Keelan, I couldn't figure out how to add a page to help center though...

Comment: I think Skeptics just uses a meta post for that. But maybe it's not so necessary, and we can see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, we should not adopt a homework policy, and the close reasons list should stay as-is.