# 'Missing context' close reason: remove 'other details'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

We currently have a close reason that was [originally intended for zero-effort homework](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3057/2953) and now reads:

> This question is missing context or other details. Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

While I still disagree that this should be a close reason, I accept that it's there... but I am unhappy about the 'other details' part.

It makes the OP think: 'Well, hm, I don't see how this question is missing context... so apparently this question is missing *other details* — what could that be?' The OP jumps to conclusions because he doesn't want to admit his question is lacking context, and isn't helped by the 'other details' clause, because it is unclear.

In such a case, it would be preferable to use the last close reason:

> Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

This forces the closers to explain what is wrong and thus helps the OP better.

I therefore suggest changing the close reason to:

> This question is missing context. Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: This seems solid to me! "Other details" is probably glossing for things like "philosophical motivation" which is sort of difficult to spell out in the terse language of these close reasons

Comment: I don't know why "other details" ended up in it (as in I don't see the need for it and don't remember how we put that in).

Comment: I've started the process to change it. If Joseph or another mod can "approve" then we are golden.

Comment: Judging from the original thread, the *or other details* part is due to a copy-paste of the Math.SE example provided by @fileunderwater. I support the effort to cross this out, as it really is redundant and distracts from the actual problem adressed by the vote.

Comment: status-completed tag added.