# Student assignments

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I believe that blatant student-assignment questions like [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/system-levels-related-to-the-fulfillment-of-individual-needs) should be closed, but I don't think that any of the current reasons for closing apply clearly to this case.

How is this situation dealt with in other communities? Should there be another reason for closing tailored to this and similar cases?

Comment: The way that those questions are/have been dealt with here is to explain to the person that this isn't a website where people do their homework for them and ask them to show what attempts they've made at answering the question. If/when they refuse to edit their question, the question is usually closed. I think its a big issue when some people see these questions and answer them anyway despite it being obvious that they're "blatant student-assignment questions", but the process of closing the question usually takes enough time to allow people to answer the questions.

Comment: The close option under off-topic "This question is missing context. Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level" covers the basic idea, even if it doesn't mention homework specifically.

Comment: [Actually this is pretty much a doubly duplicate question](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/should-we-have-a-homework-policy). So yes, that close option is the homework related option. I think the discussion Joseph and Keelan had about whether or not to add a policy to the help page is interesting, but I think it's a bad idea to not have a policy explicitly stated.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that other discussion. I'm really bad at finding duplicate questions when SE doesn't find them for me ./

Comment: Here is the [other question](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/add-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-homework) so that it appears in the list of Linked

Comment: @JosephWeissman There seemed to be pretty high approval of adding "no-effort homework" closing reason back in 2016. Do you know why it was not added?

Comment: I think it WAS added, but the reason explanation reads closer to “missing context” than “this is homework”